# Firefox/Seamonkey freezing on loading first tab

Tags: firefox, freeze, crash, seamonkey

Since 2 weeks, Firefox and Seamonkey both started freezing when loading the first "real" Tab. "Real" means that they can load the interface and the "restore last session" page, but they cannot load any website without freezing completely. I have to kill the process in the Task Manager.

As far as I see, those 2 don't share any folders (both default installation), the only common thing is that they are using the same rendering engine.

I'm using the latest version as of today in both browsers.

How can I get my browsers back to work? I already tried uninstalling/reinstalling. Did not change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was within Greasemonkey. I deactivated Greasemonkey (no scripts, just the GM-Plugin) and it works again.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your graphics drivers are up to date. At least on Windows, Firefox is trying to use your graphics card for rendering by default, which it hasn't done for most of its existence (it's a fairly new feature). This of course triggers tons of bugs in graphics drivers that are otherwise not designed to handle the pressures of rendering the web.

Try creating a new Mozilla profile by passing the `-P` or `-profilemanager` switches to the command (this is very platform/version/program-specific so I'll leave it to Mozilla to explain in depth): http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_Manager